# How to run stopwatch infinitely

Tags: c#, winforms, stopwatch

I am working on a windows forms application and I want to calculate elapsed time infinitely until I tell it to stop by the use of a boolean flag in my code that will control the execution flow.

The only sample code I have is the one provided by MSDN. But now, the problem is that it calculates the time for 10 seconds only which makes sense seeing that the thread is being put to sleep for only 10 seconds and then afterwards the stopwatch is stopped.

I strongly believe the use of `Thread.Sleep(10000)` is the major hindrance here. Please find below the MSDN code used in reference here:

```
 private string CalculateDowntime()
{ 
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        return elapsedTime);;
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

**Update:**
To further clarify, upon button click, I want to calculate time (whether its using a stopwatch or timer, I really don't care) infinitely until I tell it to stop. **That's all!**

Comment: If you want to keep the stopwatch running indefinitely then surely it is as easy as not calling `stopWatch.Stop()`

Comment: can you please specify when you want to start the stopwatch and how exactly you intend to use a boolean flag to stop it?

Comment: What happens in your code when you don't sleep the thread and don't stop the stopwatch?  What isn't working?

Comment: As per @David's comment, when I don't start the thread and stop the stop watch, put breakpoints and step through my code, it actually calculates the elapsed time infinitely but problem is that it does not update the label text on my form.

Comment: @Harold_Finch: I don't see where in the code you're attempting to update a label.

Comment: @Harold_Finch: As an aside, are you sure you want to use a `Stopwatch` and not a `Timer`?  The latter seems more suitable for what you may be trying to achieve.

Comment: @David Any approach that can get me what I want will do. Can you post something using a timer?

Comment: the better you manage to specify and explain what exactly you are trying to do, the better the people will be able to help you.

Comment: Are you wanting to have the label text update from the stopwatch continually or only when certain events happen? ie do you just display the time when a button is clicked or is it more like watching a real stopwatch where you can see the time ticking up constantly?

Comment: @Harold_Finch: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx  Or possibly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx

Comment: @MongZhu As the question suggests, upon button click, I want to calculate time (whether its using a stopwatch or timer, I really don't care) infinitely until I tell it to stop.

Comment: @MongZhu I'm assuming its you that gave the downvote? The question cannot be any more simpler than how it already is.

Comment: Then the answer posted by Derek should entirely satisfy your needs, if this is your complete description

Comment: I very seldomly downvote a question. And in your case I did not :)

Comment: @MongZhu Thanks for helping me scrutinize his solution a little more.

Comment: @Harold_Finch you are welcome. There are dozens of solution to such a problem that you encountered. But the most of them will fit only marginally to your problem. So it is worth to put a little more effort into the specification and explanation of what exactly one tries to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the stopwatch variable a property on your class.

Add methods to start / stop the stop watch.

You can also get the elapsed time after stopping.

Here is example code in a wpf program with two buttons:

When you click the start button the timer will start, when you click the stop button the timer will stop and show a message box with the elapsed milliseconds.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;

namespace StopWatch
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      public Stopwatch MyStopWatch = new Stopwatch();

      private void Start_Button_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
      {
         MyStopWatch.Start();
      }

      private void Stop_Button_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
      {
         MyStopWatch.Stop();
         MessageBox.Show( MyStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() );
      }
   }
}
```